# Why does typescript infer the type of SVG imports as "any" in NextJs 14

Tags: typescript, svg, next.js, eslint, next.js13

I'm working on a NextJs 14 project using the app router, typescript and eslint. In my app folder I have an assets folder with some jpg and SVG images. Im importing these images into an index.ts file within the the same folder and exporting an object variable named images which contains all the images and has the signature:

```
Export const images: {[key : string] : StaticImageData} = {image1, image2, image3}
```

But what I noticed was that jpg imports are correctly inferred as StaticImageData while SVG imports are being inferred as any. When I run eslint, it complains that I'm unsafely assigning value of any. How do I get fix all this without disabling any TS config rules

Comment: svg is not a StaticImageData as it is basically is text instead of an image. If I recall correctly, it is something like `React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>`

Comment: @grekier so how do I get typescript to use that as the type.  Also keep in mind that I plan on using these imported assets as the src of next js' Image component which only except string | StaticImageData

Comment: I don't think you can use svg in Image src but you can use it directly in JSX (without Image or img tag)